# Override Caps Lock with Ctrl using C#

Tags: c#, capslock, remap, ctrl

I'm writing (*yet another*, I know) keyboard remapper using C# and Visual Studio 2008.

I followed [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx) to learn how to snap up low-level key presses. This works just fine for overriding e.g. normal alphabetical characters on my keyboard, but I seem to need a bit more to make <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> act like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

My understanding (which may be incorrect) is that <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> are handled completely different from one another since <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is a toggling key whereas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is just a "normal" one.

So what I'm trying to understand here is how to make <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> behave like a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on the very lowest level and also how to make the normal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key act like a <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key.

Thanks

Comment: I would say, why do you want this?  If you don't want the data entered  in all caps, then have a post-input step that changes the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain a bool which represents expected state of caps lock.
When caps lock key is hit, set the systems's <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> value back to the bool's value.
When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is hit, toggle the expected state of the caps lock and set the system's cap lock value to the bool's value.

Use the following to set the initial expected state:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Winapi)] 
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode); 
bool CapsLock = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
```

Add special logic in HookCallback (from the link you provided) for when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> are hit. Caps lock is when lParam is `&H14`. Ctrl is when lParam is `&H11`.

To get/set the system's <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> value:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/fb8308e5-7620-43cc-8ad8-be67d94708fa/